# clojure - leiningen could not find deeplearning4j artifact via maven

Tags: java, maven, clojure, leiningen

I am trying to take a next step in my clojure/leiningen learning process.

I would like to import [deeplearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.org/) in my clojure project. Doing some research, it seems possible to do it with leiningen via maven. According to the [tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md), the maven libraries are from [here](https://search.maven.org/).

The process I expected to work was to look for the library (deeplearning4j in this case) and add it to the `project.clj` as such:

```clj
(defproject to-remove "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j "1.0.0-beta7"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot to-remove.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all
                       :jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true"]}})
```

But I get the error:

```sh
Could not find artifact org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j:jar:1.0.0-beta7 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j:jar:1.0.0-beta7 in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

I tried to add in the `:repositories` key, but also with no luck:

```clj
(defproject to-remove "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j "1.0.0-beta7"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot to-remove.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all
                       :jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true"]}}
  :repositories [["maven-org" "https://search.maven.org/"]
                 ["maven-source" "https://mvnrepository.com/"]])
```

got me the error:

```sh
Retrieving org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/1.0.0-beta7/deeplearning4j-1.0.0-beta7.jar from maven-org
Retrieving org/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/1.0.0-beta7/deeplearning4j-1.0.0-beta7.jar from maven-org
Apr 30, 2021 11:41:12 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: MVN_SESSION=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7InVpZCI6IjFjMTU0ZTQxLWE5YzItMTFlYi1hOTA5LTBiOWZkMzcxZjc1ZiJ9LCJleHAiOjE2NTEzMjk2NzIsIm5iZiI6MTYxOTc5MzY3MiwiaWF0IjoxNjE5NzkzNjcyfQ.onpYZCJmVMQt6ue-orMHPFCR6XxJb896QwbpMylElf4; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Sat, 30 Apr 2022 14:41:12 GMT; SameSite=Lax; Path=/; HTTPOnly". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Sat, 30 Apr 2022
14:41:12 GMT
Could not find artifact org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j:jar:1.0.0-beta7 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j:jar:1.0.0-beta7 in clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/)
Could not transfer artifact org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j:jar:1.0.0-beta7 from/to maven-org (https://search.maven.org/): Checksum
validation failed, expected <!-- but is 6316efb328e43503f4e6869fa876dc6eb0e7a39b
Could not find artifact org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j:jar:1.0.0-beta7 in maven-source (https://mvnrepository.com/)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

Could anyone help me understand what I am getting wrong?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `project.clj`, use id `org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core`, not  `org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j`. You may need to look at this [information on Deeplearning4J dependencies](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/getting-started/quickstart#using-dl-4-j-in-your-own-projects-configuring-the-pom-xml-file) as you may need some others.

Comment: interesting. `lein deps` worked using your suggestion. Thx! Would you know why there is a org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j in the maven repo but not "importable" via clojure?

Comment: The Maven artifact `org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j` is imported by other projects as a parent POM and has no actual content other than build configuration. Deeplearning4j is divided into several projects which share that configuration. As a user of Deeplearning4j, you only need depend on the project(s) required.